# How do I change the keybindings for the dialog command

Tags: bash, dialog

According to the documentation [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog):

> You can override or add to key bindings in dialog by adding to the
>   configuration file. Dialog's bindkey command maps single keys to its
>   internal coding.
>
> bindkey widget curses_key dialog_key
>
> The widget name can be "*" (all
>   widgets), or specific widgets such as textbox. Specific widget
>   bindings override the "*" bindings. User-defined bindings override the
>   built-in bindings. The curses_key can be any of the names derived from
>   curses.h, e.g., "HELP" from "KEY_HELP". Dialog also recognizes ANSI
>   control characters such as "^A", "^?", as well as C1-controls such as
>   "~A" and "~?". Finally, it allows any single character to be escaped
>   with a backslash.
>
> Dialog's internal keycode names correspond to the DLG_KEYS_ENUM type
>   in dlg_keys.h, e.g., "HELP" from "DLGK_HELP".

So I did the following:

```
dialog --create-rc dialogrc
export DIALOGRC=/home/MyUser/dialogrc
```

And then I added this to the bottom of my dialogrc:

```
bindkey * \r ITEM_NEXT
bindkey * \w FIELD_NEXT
bindkey * \e GRID_DOWN
```

I did all those as I'm not entirely sure which one I want. I start my dialog like this:

```
dialog --clear --backtitle "Test" --menu "key test" 15 50 4 Option1 "Option1" Option2 "Option2" Option3 "Option3"
```

I know it's reading my dialogrc file as the colours change. However the w, e and r keys do nothing. I want to be able to move up and down between menu items by pressing a key other than the up or down arrow.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the version of dialog supplied by my package manager was out of date. Compiled from [here](http://invisible-island.net/dialog/#download) and it works as expected.